# How use multi gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, multi-gpu

I want to use the tensorflow multi gpu. Currently, there are two GPUs `#0`, `#1`, and if you run `nvidia-smi` and see GPU usage rate, only `#0` GPU is used ~35%. I wonder how you can use both `0#` and `1#` 99%.

This code is added and executed before the learning code. I didn't know how to use both 0 and 1, so I only used 0 but only 35%.

```
tf.device("/device:GPU:0")

    config=tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9       

    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess :
        while(True) :
            prev_cost = 9999999999
            break_condition_count = 0
. . .
```

The learning code begins briefly like this.

1. How can I use both 0 and 1 GPU?
2. I'd like to raise the GPU usage rate from 35% to 99%. What should I do?

I've searched so many times that I couldn't find a way. I'm sorry.
I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Here is some documentation on how to use multiple GPUs: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus

Comment: For your second question, there are many parameters that are not visible in the GPU usage. For example, you could have a bottleneck on I/O to and from your GPU, or on compute that happens before and after the compute that occurs on your GPU (for example CPU data augmentation). So having your GPU usage not at 100% is usually because something else is taking time

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me check.